# Restore ESP partition after accidental format

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, boot-repair

While installing a new SSD to my Ubuntu server I have made the grave mistake of formatting a partition on the wrong drive. I've accidentally formatted the ESP partition of my HDD that contains the OS. This has lead to Ubuntu not booting at all anymore and the PC just telling me `reboot and select proper boot device`.

I've googled all around, find posts telling me to use the Ubuntu Live usb and select "Rescue a broken system", but those posts are all very old and neither the Ubuntu server nor normal image show me that option. I'm writing the images with Rufus as GPT so I'm able to boot the usb through UEFI. Another post mentioned selecting "reinstall ubuntu" after selecting "install ubuntu" but I don't have that option.

I've tried boot repair both through Ubuntu live usb and as standalone live usb, but it returns 3 commands of which the last one fails. After I click continue it tells me grub is still present and to try again. I googled that too and they recommended editing the last command, but that didn't work either.

Could someone point me in the right direction and tell me if this is even possible? It's 5 am and I've been at this for 4 hours straight trying to get my server back up and running, hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy the bootloaders off the install media onto your EFI partition.
Put grubx64.efi into .../EFI/boot/grubx64.efi and into .../EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
get the UUID of your root, and put it into the grub.cfg stub file in ...EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg (and change the hd1 (disk) and gpt2 (partition) to match your root also. Here's a sample stub grub.cfg

```
search.fs_uuid your-root-uuid-here root hd1,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

The bootloaders on the install media are in the /EFI directory.  mount your EFI, say in /mnt/xxx, and copy the files to /mnt/xxx/EFI/boot etc.
You might want to remove the 14.04 tag, nothing here is OS specific, and 14.04 is end of life and out of scope.

Comment: Hi I did exactly this but I still get the "reboot and select proper boot device". I've mounted the ESP partition, changed ownership of all the files to root (as I copied a load of random files over it) and removed all of it. Made an EFI folder and then boot and ubuntu folders in that, pasted grub file, created the grub.cfg file and entered my info. I assume it's the UUID of the partition that has my ubuntu OS files and hd1 and gpt2 is /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb9 as those are my harddrive and ubuntu partitions. I'm pretty new, did I misunderstand anything? Does the file ownership matter?

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood some things, but the main issue seemed to be that the ESP partition was formatted as ext4. I eventually tried to install ubuntu to another partition to see if that would restore the ESP partition, but I got an error saying it tried to mount it as vfat. So I formatted the partition as fat and copied back the folders and files from your answer (with proper hd and gpt) and it booted!